# SQL query to only get results where all requested 2-column matches occur

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a result where column 1's value can be found for three (or more) combinations of column 2 & 3 (pair-wise?) Example... here's a hypothetical table of 3 columns:

```
FRUIT   |  TRAIT    |   DESCRIBED
-------------------------------
Apple   |  color    |  red 
Apple   |  shape    |  round
Pear    |  surface  |  smooth 
pear    |  stem     |  red 
grape   |  shape    |  round 
grape   |  color    |  red 
grape   |  surface  |  smooth
```

I want to find fruit that have a shape=round, are color=red and surfaced=smooth. The result in the above table should be "grape", but my attempts at figuring out the right sql query, I can't narrow it down. I get Apple, because it's red, and pear because it's smooth. But I don't want those. I want a fruit that shows up for all three trait/described values.

I've gotten this far, thinking there was a way to use group, and I used Subqueries - thinking that would give me a way to require. But it still doesn't give me just 'grape' in results.

```
 SELECT fruit /* DISTINCT ?*/ FROM table1 WHERE fruit 
 IN  (SELECT fruit FROM table1 WHERE trait = 'shape' AND described = 'round')
 AND (SELECT fruit FROM table1 WHERE trait = 'color' AND described = 'red')
 AND (SELECT fruit FROM table1 WHERE trait = 'surface' AND described = 'smooth')     
 HAVING count(fruit) = 3   /* or whatever number of trait/described combos were searched for */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were oh so close. Just keep selecting fruit from your clauses and don't worry about the count - also you were right to use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT FRUIT FROM Table1 
WHERE FRUIT IN (SELECT FRUIT FROM Table1 WHERE TRAIT = 'shape' AND DESCRIBED = 'round')
AND FRUIT IN (SELECT FRUIT FROM Table1 WHERE TRAIT = 'color' AND DESCRIBED = 'red')
AND FRUIT IN (SELECT FRUIT FROM Table1 WHERE TRAIT = 'surface' AND DESCRIBED = 'smooth')
```

You can do your testing on the [SQL Fiddle I used](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb01e0/6)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT fruit 
FROM table1 
WHERE (trait, described) IN ( ('shape', 'round'), ('color', 'red'), ('surface', 'smooth') )  
GROUP BY fruit 
HAVING count(fruit) = 3  ;
```

This is much simpler to read, write, and maintain than a query that has unnecessary subqueries.  As for performance, the `SELECT DISTINCT` is essentially the same as a `GROUP BY` from a performance perspective and this doesn't do unnecessary subqueries.  So it should win on that front as well.

Comment: That looks promising for me...but in my actual table test, it's giving zero results? ... SELECT Entity_id FROM field_plant_descriptors WHERE (field_plant_descriptors_plant_part_described, field_plant_descriptors_description_term) IN ( (8770, 8060 ), (8758, 8109), (8773, 8236) ) GROUP BY Entity_id HAVING count(Entity_id) = 3

Comment: scratch that... just a typo. Thank you! I might go with this one. I do like that there are no subqueries

Comment: By the way, is there a way to have the count automatically match the number of sets in the IN section? I've seen something like that before, but not for this. Searching around right now for that syntax

Comment: @turpentyne . . . One method is to implement such logic with a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to get the fruits who have all these properties you can use aggregation

```
SELECT FRUIT
FROM table1
GROUP BY FRUIT
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TRAIT = 'color' AND DESCRIBED = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN TRAIT = 'shape' AND DESCRIBED = 'round' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN TRAIT = 'surface' AND DESCRIBED = 'smooth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1953f6/4)

Using Mysql you could also use `sum(a=b)`, `SUM(TRAIT = 'color' AND DESCRIBED = 'red' )` as shorthand, using expression inside `sum()` will result you a boolean value 0/1, true/false

Comment: dbmitch's solution worked for me, but are there some benefits to the method above that might make it a better approach?

Comment: @user3385160 you can see it does all the logic using single query not involving sub queries, also i am not sure about the performance you could run explain plan for both queries and decide